# Gitpython to initialize and push a new repo

Tags: python, gitpython

So I'm trying to use gitpython (https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) to do something relatively simple but having trouble.

So I've got a blank brand new repo on my bitbucket server, then I'm using gitpython to initialize a local repo, add a file, and commit successfully.

However, where I'm having trouble is pushing these changes to the brand new blank remote bitbucket repo I have. I've tried several things but I always get
`git push --set-upstream origin master` as the error returned. But when I navigate to the the repo directory, I can see it's on the master branch, and I can see the remote repo URL when I run `git status` and `git remote -v`.

```
def commit_files(url):
    repo_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tmp')
    file_name = os.path.join(repo_dir, 'Jenkinsfile')

    repo = git.Repo.init(repo_dir)
    open(file_name, "wb").close()
    repo.index.add([file_name])
    repo.index.commit("initial commit")
    repo.create_remote("origin", url=url)
    repo.remote("origin").push()
```

All of the documentation and SO posts I've found only seem to go over pushing to an already existing repo after cloning it.

Comment: is Repo (R in capital) a keyword of gitpython as seen in `git.Repo.init`?

Answer (score 2):

This one gave me a hard time too, since I tried the same as you, apparently:

1. Create a new remote Git repository.
2. Create a new local Git repository (not cloning the remote one).
3. Add some changes to my local repository.
4. Tried to push my changes to the remote repository.

I finally found the reason in this to fail in the missing [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) between the local and remote repository:

> In the default case that is automatically written by a `git remote add origin` command, Git fetches all the references under `refs/heads/` on the server and writes them to `refs/remotes/origin/` locally.

It can be solved by adding a refspec to the `.push()` method like this:

```
repo.remote("origin").push('+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*')
```

This should be able to be avoided, but I could not figure out how; the author seems to prefer for people to apply a workaround than to answer the question on how to do this at [Github Issue #549](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/549)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a work around just by cloning the blank repo, making the changes, and pushing. Not what I wanted but a sufficient solution. Also needed to provide auth credentials in my case.

```
def commit_files(url):
    repo_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tmp')
    file_name = os.path.join(repo_dir, 'Jenkinsfile')

    repo = git.Repo.clone_from(url, repo_dir, env={"GIT_SSH_COMMAND": 'ssh -i /PATH/TO/KEY'})
    open(file_name, "wb").close()
    repo.index.add([file_name])
    repo.index.commit("initial commit")
    repo.remote("origin").push()

    return
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide target branch

```
repo.remote("origin").push("master")
```